# Kubernetes configmap name is not picked up by springboot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am integrating kubernetes configmap with my springboot application. I created config-map, given its name in my bootstrap.yml file and have a simple RestController to read the properties. However, the name of the configmap is not picked up by the pod. In the logs of the pod I see the name of the configmap as 'default'. I don't know what's going wrong. Appreciate any help!

```
 Located property source: ConfigMapPropertySource [name='configmap.application.default']
```

Here is my configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: echo-configmap
data:
  application.yml: |-
    bean:
      message: Hello from Kubernetes Configmap
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
           <version>0.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

bootstrap.yml

```
 spring:
 application:
  name: echo-configmap

 cloud:
kubernetes:
  reload:
     enabled: true
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
 @EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bean")
public class EchoConfigController {

@Value("${message}")
private String message;



@RequestMapping(value="/echo", method=GET)
public String printKubeConfig() {
    System.out.println("EchoController is invoked ");
    System.out.println("message = "+message);
    return message;
}
```

}

Kubernetes pod logs:

```
[kubernetes1@se-docker-int-2 ~]$ kubectl logs echo-deployment-2968296553-h8m1q
04:53:33.873 [main] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config - Trying to configure client from Kubernetes config...
2018-01-14 04:53:42.122  INFO 7 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: ConfigMapPropertySource [name='configmap.application.default']
 2018-01-14 04:53:42.125  INFO 7 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: SecretsPropertySource [name='secrets.application.default']
2018-01-14 04:53:42.181  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.o.a.c.EchoServiceApplication           : The following profiles are active: kubernetes
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the name of the ConfigMap, it's the name of the kubernetes namespace in which it's running, [as seen here](https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/master/spring-cloud-kubernetes-core/src/main/java/io/fabric8/spring/cloud/kubernetes/config/ConfigMapPropertySource.java#L55-L59), showing that in your example the "name" is `application`.

You didn't actually say whether you tested the RestController, to say what it returns (and/or emits to stdout); did your `GET` produce any output, or are you asking this question solely based on that log message?

---

> bootstrap.yml

```
 spring:
 application:
  name: echo-configmap
```

I can't tell if you have just mis-copy-pasted, but if you really do have the `spring:` key indented in your `bootstrap.yml`, then that file will be mis-parsed by Spring, causing the spring.application.name to not be what you think.

---

```
data:
  application.yml: |-
    bean:
      message: Hello from Kubernetes Configmap
...
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bean")
```

Foremost, you are treading on thin ice by naming your `ConfigurationProperties` prefix a very generic word like `bean`. Secondarily, you are making things harder by causing your `RestController` to serve as your `ConfigurationProperties` instance, too, since they have very, very different lifecycles within Spring. Thirdly, I would need to test it to say with certainty, but `@Value` is traditionally used to inject a SPeL value into some other bean, not a random field in the `ConfigurationProperties` -- you'll get a lot further by just making `message` into a normal JavaBean property via its `getMessage()/setMessage()` accessor/mutator pattern. Plus, doing it that way has the very, very real benefit that you can set a breakpoint inside the `get` or `set` method and see for yourself that Spring is calling them with the values you expect.

Comment: I defined the name of the configmap as echo-configmap and i expect the pod to pick it up. For whatever reasons, it is not detecting the name of the configmap and using the default name - application. I created a configmap by name application and it started working.  My rest-controller is printing the output fine. My challenge now is to make the application read the actual config map. Any ideas are highly appreciated

Comment: One will observe I spoke to 3 different parts of your post; is your `bootstrap.yml` actually indented as you have pasted?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the application name in the environment, or by System property: `env SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME="echo-configmap"` or `-Dspring.application.name="echo-configmap"`?

Comment: The issue was that I didn't package my application.properties in the JAR file. Hence the application name was not read. After fixing the packaging it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't package my application.properties in the JAR file. Hence the application name was not read. After fixing the packaging it worked